# Image displaying from database

Tags: php, mysql, image, image-gallery

I am trying to show images from database with next previous button.

here's my code:

```
<?PHP
session_start();
$page = "voting.php";
include ('dbconnect.php');
$q = "SELECT * FROM vote_frames";
$r = mysql_query($q);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)){
    $i_array[] = $row['frame_pic'];
    $i_array1[] = $row['frame_pic1'];
    $i_array2[] = $row['frame_pic2'];
    $id_array[] = $row['frame_id'];
}
$fpp = 1;
$num_images = count($i_array);
$image_path = "frames/";
$y = $fpp;
if(!isset($_GET['first'])){
        $first = 0;
    }else{
        $first = (int) $_GET['first'];
}
$x = $num_images - 1;
$z = $x - $y;
if($first>$z) {
    $first = $z;
}
$last = $first + $fpp;
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
</head>
<body>

<div>
                <?PHP
                $i = $first;
                $prev = $first-1;
                $next = $first +1;
                if($prev<0){ $prev = 0; }
                ?><a href="<?PHP echo $page; ?>?first=<?PHP echo $prev; ?>">Previous</a><?PHP
                while($i<$last) { 
                    $f = $image_path . $i_array[$i];
                    $f1 = $image_path . $i_array1[$i];
                    $f2 = $image_path . $i_array2[$i];
                    ?>
                    <img src="<?PHP echo $f; ?>">
                    <img src="<?PHP echo $f1; ?>">
                    <img src="<?PHP echo $f2; ?>">
                    <?PHP 
                    $i++; 
                }
                ?><a href="<?PHP echo $page; ?>?first=<?PHP echo $next; ?>"><Next</a><?PHP
                ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Images are displaying but with a strange behavior that last record is not showing. Actually for testing when I echoed id of current showing record, it shows next's id so record is having id of next's.

I know I can do it with jquery w/o any issue but I must use a way to store current showing pic's id in session so I can show current showing and its next picture's vote count in the graph below.

Any take on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part here is VERY cryptic, why you have written it that way? I assume you have tested several ways to do it, but ... clean up code, while you correct or test it. That way it's not too cryptic to read.

```
$fpp = 1;
$num_images = count($i_array);
$image_path = "frames/";
$y = $fpp;
if(!isset($_GET['first'])){
        $first = 0;
    }else{
        $first = (int) $_GET['first'];
}
$x = $num_images - 1;
$z = $x - $y;
if($first>$z) {
    $first = $z;
}
$last = $first + $fpp;
```

And there is your problem too `$x` is number of images minus one, and `$z` is `$x` minus `$y` (which is one, cryptically yes). Which means `$z` is `number of images minus 2`. Thats why last record is not showing. Clean up that code, and it starts working, it would be easy to fix, but I'll leave it to you as practise.